# For loop to difference columns that are not stationary while not changing stationary columns

Tags: python, for-loop, diff, forecasting

I would like to difference all the columns in my data frame `train_WE_exog_A` if they are not stationary. The self-defined function returns 1 if not stationary, and 0 if stationary. Besides differencing the columns that are not stationary, I would like to keep track of which columns weren't differences because I will have to reverse the procedure at a later point (for forecasting).

The code I tried now:

```
diff = []

for name, column in train_WE_exog_A_2019.iteritems():
    res = adfuller_test(column, name=column.name)
    diff.append(res)
    if res == 1:
        train_exog_diff.column = column.diff().dropna()
```

The problem is that this code doesn't actually difference the columns. When I would run another for loop to again perform the adfuller_test(), I get the exact same list of 1s and 0s. Ideally, the loop would difference until stationary, but if it does so once, it's already a game-changer.

```
# The result I get with running the above loop: 
>>>diff
[1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]

# The result I get with running the adfull_test() again to check whether differencing worked: 
>>>diff2
[1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]

>>>diff == diff2
True
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:

1. Changing the adfuller_test() function so that it returns the name of the column when that column is NOT stationary
2. Updated the for loop such that it creates a list of NON-stationary columns.
3. This makes it easy to use with slicing.

```
# Use function in a for loop to append all non-stationary column names to a list
diff = []
for name, column in train_WE_exog_A_2019.iteritems():
    res = adfuller_test(column, name=column.name)
    if res != None:
        diff.append(res)

train_WE_exog_A_2019[diff] = train_WE_exog_A_2019[diff].diff().fillna(0)
```

FYI, the function I adapted can be found on this webpage: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/vector-autoregression-examples-python/